# Add Custom Attribute to New Order Email Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

I added a custom attribute in to my default product type like so

Attribute Code: mfgpartnumber
Attribute Label:  Manufacturer Part Number

This attribute is used to add products in Magento backend and I want to include this attribute in new order emails. I have researched so far and here is what I finally added

```
<?php $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $_item->getSku(), array('mfgpartnumber')); ?>
<?php echo $product->getAttributeText('mfgpartnumber'); ?>
```

To /home/txsystems/store/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order

That did not work, please can someone point me in the right direction on how to add custom attribute to Magento new order emails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer not to use loadByAttribute as it returns a [resource collection](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/6ea22c9abff24da3f3f2aaed59c527ff803c02eb/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Abstract.php#L224-L235) call which uses "select *" by default. Try this instead:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Answer (score 0):

To add custom fields to Order Email, open the order email template located at

```
app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html

app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new_guest.html
```

add the below code where you want

```
{{depend order.hasCustomFields()}}

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">

<thead>

<tr>

<th align="left" width="325" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:5px 9px 6px 9px; line-height:1em;">Custom Fields:</th>

</tr>

</thead>

<tbody>

<tr>

<td valign="top" style="font-size:12px; padding:7px 9px 9px 9px; border-left:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-bottom:1px solid #EAEAEA; border-right:1px solid #EAEAEA;">

{{var order.getFieldHtml()}}

&nbsp;

</td>

</tr>

</tbody>

</table>

{{/depend}}

<br/>
```

So as per the above code, you need two functions hasCustomFields() and getFieldHtml() in our Order class. So next you will override the Mage_Sales_Model_Order model. Open your `config.xml` file and inside  section put in this code

```
<sales>

<rewrite>

<order>Excellence_Custom_Model_Sales_Order</order>

</rewrite>

</sales>
```

and next create our new model class Excellence_Custom_Model_Sales_Order

```
<?php

class Excellence_Custom_Model_Sales_Order extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order{

public function hasCustomFields(){

$var = $this->getSsn();

if($var && !empty($var)){

return true;

}else{

return false;

}

}

public function getFieldHtml(){

$var = $this->getSsn();

$html = '<b>SSN:</b>'.$var.'<br/>';

return $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way is not to load the product by the item ID, but simply getting the product via the item:

```
$customAttribute = $_item->getProduct()->getCustomAttribute();
```

or

```
$customAttributeText = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('custom_attribute');
```

And using that